# How to save the object recognition result?

Tags: swift, uikit, coreml

I am trying to make a simple application that can recognize food in real time. Everything works, but I can't figure out how to save the result. Through print, I can output it to the console but not write it, for example, to UILabel, etc.I would like that after the application recognizes the object, it would display the name in the UILabel and after I click on the button, I can save the result I need with the UILabel into a variable. That is, when we hover over a banana, for example, UILabel should show the word banana and after I click the button the following should happen: var item = label.text

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 30, width: 100, height: 50))
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
      label.textColor = .black
      button.backgroundColor = .green
    
      button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
      self.view.addSubview(label)
      self.view.addSubview(button)
    
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
    
    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
    guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
    captureSession.addInput(input)
    
    captureSession.startRunning()
    
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    
    let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
    captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    guard let pixBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    guard let model =  try? VNCoreMLModel(for: SqueezeNet().model) else {return}
   
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (res, error) in
        guard let results = res.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
        guard let observationData = results.first else { return }
        //let alert = UIAlertController(title: observationData.identifier + "Это он ?", message: "Угадал ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
       // alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
      //  self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(observationData.identifier, observationData.confidence)
        self.label.text? = String(observationData.identifier)
    }
    try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
  var item = label.text!
}
```

}

But when I try to do it Nothing happens. Xcode writes UILabel.text must be used from main thread only But unfortunately I don't understand this. Can you help me solve my problem and explain how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you run a search for 'main thread' and help yourself?

Comment: @ElTomato Because unfortunately I can't figure it out on my own. I need this for a project at the university and I hardly have time to figure it out on my own. Thank you for your understanding. If you can help me, I will be very happy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102035/swift-update-ui-entire-function-on-main-thread-or-just-the-ui-update

Comment: @cora I tried  
            guard let results = res.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
            guard let observationData = results.first else { return }
          
            print(observationData.identifier, observationData.confidence)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {self.label.text? = String(observationData.identifier)}
            
        }
        
        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }
    
But it did not help. I can't figure out what to do

Comment: Did you even add the label as subview? It’s really hard to read your code

Comment: @cora self.view.addSubview(label) - yes

Comment: @cora 
I found a bug. You gave me an idea. Thank you so much